# Slow Trigger performance when big batches

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, trigger

I have an update trigger that inserts into auditing tables.  We had no problem until someone decides to update over 1 million records... (That's my bad. I didn't think it would be a problem when developing).
Now facing reality, I need to find a solution...

I've been doing many tests and researches to try to figure out how to solve my issue of having a trigger perform poorly... 
I've come to the conclusion that to minimize the bad performance of the "Table Insert" in the execution plan, I need to insert in smaller batches.

The question is:  Since I'm not sure of where all the different updates can come from, I'm trying to figure out how I can insert the auditing records in batches within the trigger?

example, The update of the main table for 1 million records would happen and call the trigger, which would insert 100 thousand records at a time in some type of loop.

Is this possible? If so, how do you suggest?
If not, how else can I improve the table insert of the execution plan?

**Addition of test scripts to reproduce:**

This is a simplified version of the real thing

```
-- drop trigger PriceHist_trig_U 
-- drop table MyPriceTable
-- drop table price_history
Create Table MyPriceTable (SKU varchar(13), PriceGroup varchar(5), PriceLevel int, Price float, Qty float, ManyOtherColumns Varchar(100)
CONSTRAINT [PRICE_TAB_P01] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    SKU ASC,
    PriceGroup ASC,
    PriceLevel ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Declare @Id int
Set @Id = 1

While @Id <= 1000000
Begin 
   insert into MyPriceTable values (right('000000000000' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)),13),'Grp ' + CAST(@Id%10 as nvarchar(10)), @id%3, RAND()*(25-10)+10, 1, 'there are many other columns')
   Print @Id
   Set @Id = @Id + 1
End

-- Drop table   price_history 
create table price_history (SKU varchar(13), PriceGroup varchar(5), PriceLevel int, Price float, Qty float, ManyOtherColumns Varchar(100), historyDate datetime, ChangedColumns varchar(Max))
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX price_history_nc1 ON price_history
(
    HistoryDate ASC,
    SKU ASC,
    PriceGroup ASC,
    PriceLevel ASC
)

go
Create TRIGGER PriceHist_trig_U ON MyPriceTable FOR UPDATE 
AS 
INSERT INTO price_history (SKU, PriceGroup, PriceLevel, price, Qty, ManyOtherColumns, HistoryDate, ChangedColumns) 
            SELECT INS.SKU,INS.PriceGroup,INS.PriceLevel,INS.Price,INS.Qty,INS.ManyOtherColumns, getdate(),  
CASE WHEN update(Price) and INS.Price<>DEL.Price THEN 'Price-' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN update(Qty) and INS.Qty<>DEL.Qty THEN 'Qty-' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN update(ManyOtherColumns) and INS.ManyOtherColumns<>DEL.ManyOtherColumns THEN 'other-' ELSE '' END 
FROM INSERTED INS 
JOIN DELETED DEL ON DEL.sku=INS.sku AND DEL.PriceGroup=INS.PriceGroup AND DEL.PriceLevel=INS.PriceLevel 
WHERE  (update(Price) and INS.Price<>DEL.Price) 
    OR (update(Qty) and INS.Qty<>DEL.Qty) 
    OR (update(ManyOtherColumns) and INS.ManyOtherColumns<>DEL.ManyOtherColumns)

/* tests */ 
update MyPriceTable set price = price-1
```

When I run this with the trigger disabled, it runs in 2 seconds.
When the Trigger is enabled, it took 32 seconds to complete.
The Execution Plan shows 98% on the "Table Insert"

I've been trying to figure out how to improve the table insert, but can't find anything concrete...

I've tried with a Clustered index and the performance is worse.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I added more info to reproduce my issue

Answer (score 2):

I'm putting this here since it's a bit long, but I don't think it should qualify as an answer.  There are no answers here, just observations and advice.

**Short version**, there isn't anything that can be done to make the query go faster and achieve the same results.  You need to change the process that is feeding data into the main table if you want batching to solve the issue.  Otherwise, you have to change the history process.

First, it's not the table insert that's slowing you down, it's the query that pulls the INSERTED and DELETED tables together.

**Why Not?**

The INSERTED and DELETED tables are heaps with no indexes.  Joining them together as you are doing requires two table scans and a sort.  The larger the operation, the more expensive this gets.

**Batching Inside the Trigger**

This won't help you here because the source tables are heaps.  You can't walk them without creating some sort of key to work with, and adding anything will just increase (at worst) or just increase complexity (best case) without improving anything.

**Batching Outside the Trigger**

If you can rearrange so that you are doing smaller update statements at a shot outside the trigger then the INSERTED/DELETED tables will be smaller, making the operation faster and less blocking, although total cost will be the same.

**Solution(s)?**

Any solution that addresses this will require a change in some fashion.  You don't mention your version of SQL, but if you are on 2016 or better, you could look into temporal tables. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15

Alternatively, for this type of history table, where you only want to catch the UPDATES, I would do a straight insert of the DELETED table contents.  No additional comparisons or joins with the INSERTED table.  Your cost should be roughly the same as the insert, so minimal increase (I mean, double the I/O, but that's as minimal as you can get).

Then for looking at it, you just grab all the history records + the live record and you can see what changed and when.  It won't have that "ChangedColumns" list that your current version has, but you could put something like that together if you want.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm still searching for a solution that will work for all SQL versions from SQL 2008 up to date.  I can't just go with the inserted table the audit table will have unnecessary records and will grow at a much larger pace... which will create other problems since we have customers that run SQL Express and its limitations.  we also use this to deploy the changes to other machines (Store Server to cash registers or Host Server to Stores).  I've tried different solutions, including the creation of variable tables but it just made the process longer.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to create indexes on the inserted and deleted heap tables... I need to figure out how to make the join between inserted and deleted perform better.  I've also tried the trace flag 610 and adding an order by (things that I have read that would help)... but no success there.

Comment: You won't be able to do that, the INSERTED and DELETED tables are virtual and cannot be modified...without adding a sort operation which you already have done.  Have you looked into modifying the history operation itself?  Inserting just the DELETED table contents directly will be far faster than trying to join them with the INSERTED table.  What are your actual requirements with the history table, are the changed columns useful to anyone?  These tend to not be read very much.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not enough information. Useful information would be:

- The structure of the tables involved, including **indexes**
- The execution plan
- What the trigger does and what it does look like (maybe its code can be improved)
- What the auditing tables actually contain

Breaking up the process in small batches could help. Keep in mind that the trigger will be fired once per *batch* operation, regardless of whether you insert only one row or 1000 rows. Many people fall for this trap, thinking that each insert = 1 trigger invocation, but this is not true. So your trigger should be aware of the number of rows being added and act accordingly.

The lack of proper indexes could be a factor for the slow insert. Again, there is no way for us to know. You have to look at your table structure, execution plan and the code for the trigger.

In itself, inserting or updating over 1 million records is not a small operation. That operation is probably wrapped in an implicit or explicit **transaction**, which adds further overhead (by writing to the transaction logfile).

Rather than reinvent the wheel, maybe it would better to take advantage of the **auditing features** already available in SQL Server. See for example: [Understanding the SQL Server Audit](https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-sql-server-audit/). Too often, triggers are not the solution but the problem.

In fact that may not be the insert that is slow, that could be the trigger doing some calculations or fetching data to do the insert.

One thing you could is create a copy of the target table, without the trigger and simulate that mass update to measure the time difference. In other words, verify that the trigger is indeed the cause for poor performance and quantity it.
Run the execution plan and compare.

Comment: I've been checking all of this and know about the inserted\Deleted tables that contain all rows of a batch.  I will try to add some more info (as I need to recreate it in a test environment while changing names of tables and fields) but deep down, I've come to the conclusion (in the execution plan) that the bottleneck is the "table Insert").  At that point, as per my understanding, it is the physical insertion of the data.  I have also studied the different options of auditing before putting this live... The triggers were the best path to take in my case.

Comment: @Paul White 9 I got busy with some other stuff... I just added more info to reproduce as requested... Can you please re-open?

Comment: @Paul ...It has been 6 days and still, the question is closed although I added information as requested... I created a new question as the blue box suggests and... that new question was closed[duplicate]... What do I need to do to get this question re-opened?